# Can not store the result of a get call using Fetch-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, promise, es6-promise

I am using Fetch-node for a GET to a service.

```
 const response = await fetch("MY URL", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        timeout: 5000,
      }).then(res => res.json()).then(json => console.log(json));
      console.log(response);
```

I log the result in the second `console.log()` then and everything is fine.
However, when it comes to the second `console.log()` the response is undefined.
What I need is whatever is logged in the second to be stored in the response.

Is there anything wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: Then don't just log but return it...

Comment: @Andreas you mean return json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, you're not returning a value for `response`, therefore it won't be equal to anything. You could `return` the JSON from your final `then`, or if you felt it was any cleaner, just `await` both instead of using `.then` at all.

```
const response = await fetch("MY URL", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        timeout: 5000
      });

const json = await response.json();

console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return your value in your function.

```
const response = await fetch("MY URL", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        timeout: 5000,
      }).then(res => res.json()).then(json => { 
         // do something 
         return json  //<--- return a value
        });
      console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the whole code with async/await. In your code you mixed promise and async/await syntax, and forgot to return `json` from last `.then()` function.

This is how I write the code:

```js
async function fetchData() {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    timeout: 5000,
  })
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
}

fetchData();
```

Comment: Funny enough, I believe you just gave me some tips on `fetch` in the comments of another question the other day, and now here we are submitting the same answer :)

Comment: @TylerRoper I have no work... so trying everything in the internet.. :)